# How to sum a column where another column is equal to other table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 tables, `Assets` and `Main`. I want to create a query that will total the transactions in `Main`, grouped by each account in `Assets`. But there's a catch: sometimes the `amt` needs to be summed as a positive and sometimes as a negative.

In `Assets`, I have the columns `Account` and `Descript`. `Account` holds "1001", and others, as text; `Descript` is just text.

```
Account    Descript
--------------------------
1001       Cash
1101       Receivable
```

In `Main`, I have `Amt`, `Ac1`, and `Ac2`.

- `Amt` holds amounts that we need to sum
- `Ac1` and `Ac2` hold account numbers from `Assets` as text

In `Main`, when an account is marked in `Ac1`, the transaction is a positive for that account. When an account is marked in `Ac2`, the transaction amount is a
negative for that account.

Say, for one record, in Main:

1. You have -1000.00 in "Amt", you have "1001" in "Ac1", and "1101" in "Ac2".
2. You have 2000.00 in "Amt", you have "1001" in "Ac1", and "1101" in "Ac2".

Data:

```
Amt    Ac1    Ac2
-------------------
-1000  1001   1101
2000   1001   1101
```

so then the expected result needs to be:

```
Account    Descrip    TtlAmt
-------------------------------
1001       Cash        1000.00
1101       Receivable -1000.00
```

I have some code but I'm not sure if it's helpful.

```
SELECT 
    Asset.Account, Asset.Descrip AS Expr1, 
    SUM(Main.Amt) AS SumOfAMT, SUM(Main.Amt) AS Expr2
FROM 
    Asset 
LEFT JOIN 
    Main ON (Asset.ACCOUNT = Main.AC2) OR (Asset.ACCOUNT = Main.AC1)
GROUP BY 
    Asset.Account, Asset.Descrip;
```

Just to be super clear, I also have tables called "Liability", "Expense", etc. But I felt that we can focus on just the one query here, as the rest should fall into place with some guidance.

I know this has nothing to do with problem at hand, but in Excel I use the following formula to accomplish this.

```
SUM(SUMIF([sum range], [criteria range], [criteria]), SUMIF([sum range], [criteria range], [criteria])*-1)
```

I thought it may be helpful to explain my end goal.

Comment: Please edit your question by showing us sample data in _tabular_ form.  It is difficult to follow your text descriptions.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ok sure. I'm not sure how to do that. Like as an image? Can you indicate how I should do that?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Ok, I think that's better. Let me know if I should make any further edits to the tables.

Comment: Thanks, I still don't understand how you are generating the expected output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen so for 'Main', item 2, 2000.00 translates as +2000.00 for "1001", and -2000.00 for "1101"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there is a unique identifier field in Main.

Consider:

Query1

```
SELECT ID, "Ac1" AS Src, Ac1 AS Act, Amt FROM Main
UNION SELECT ID, "Ac2", Ac2, Amt*-1 FROM Main;
```

Query2

```
SELECT Query1.Act, Assets.Descrip, Sum(Query1.Amt) AS SumOfAmt
FROM Assets INNER JOIN Query1 ON Assets.Account = Query1.Act
GROUP BY Query1.Act, Assets.Descrip;
```

All in one

```
SELECT Query1.Act, Assets.Descrip, Sum(Query1.Amt) AS SumOfAmt
FROM Assets INNER JOIN
(SELECT Ac1 AS Act, Amt FROM Main
UNION SELECT Ac2, Amt*-1 FROM Main) AS Query1 
ON Assets.Account = Query1.Act
GROUP BY Query1.Act, Assets.Descrip;
```

Comment: wow this works! awesome. I have one question: What is the difference between Query2 and Query3? Cuz i'm getting the same result

Comment: The third query is a single statement that combines the other 2. See the nested UNION query.

Comment: AHH! sry i'm new. I saw the reference to "Query1" and assumed that it was referencing the first query you put up. I didn't realize how you could nest the Union Query. Awesomesauce. Made my weekend!

Comment: It was until I copy/pasted Query1 statement into Query2 between parens and added the "AS" word. Use any alias name you want, even just `Q1` - just make sure it is used every `Query1` is. Now Query1 object can be deleted if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

From a performance perspective, correlated subqueries might be a better approach:

```
select a.*,
       ( (select nz(sum(m.amt), 0)
          from main as m
          where m.ac1 = a.account
         ) -
         (select nz(sum(m.amt), 0)
          from main as m
          where m.ac2 = a.account
         )
       ) as net_amount             
from assets as a;
```

In particular, this can take advantage of two indexes:  `main(ac1, amt)` and `main(ac2.amt)`.

In addition, it eliminates the aggregation on the entire result set.